C Optimization help needed for SIMD
So far, I've got the following code.
int actualizar_tablero(int *tablero, int *tab_aux, unsigned Y, unsigned X, unsigned YX) {
    int count = 0;

    // Ensure memory alignment
    int *aligned_tablero = __builtin_assume_aligned(tablero, 16);
    int *aligned_tab_aux = __builtin_assume_aligned(tab_aux, 16);

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < Y; ++i) {
        unsigned im1 = (i == 0) ? (Y - 1) : (i - 1);
        unsigned ip1 = (i == Y - 1) ? 0 : (i + 1);

        for (unsigned j = 0; j < X; ++j) {
            unsigned jm1 = (j == 0) ? (X - 1) : (j - 1);
            unsigned jp1 = (j == X - 1) ? 0 : (j + 1);

            int vecinos = aligned_tablero[im1 * X + jm1] + aligned_tablero[im1 * X + j] +
                          aligned_tablero[im1 * X + jp1] + aligned_tablero[i * X + jm1] +
                          aligned_tablero[i * X + jp1] + aligned_tablero[ip1 * X + jm1] +
                          aligned_tablero[ip1 * X + j] + aligned_tablero[ip1 * X + jp1];

            int cell = aligned_tablero[i * X + j];
            int new_val = (cell && ((vecinos == 2) || (vecinos == 3))) || (!cell && (vecinos == 3));
            aligned_tab_aux[i * X + j] = new_val;
            count += (new_val != cell);
        }
    }

    // Copy back to tablero
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < YX; ++i) {
        aligned_tablero[i] = aligned_tab_aux[i];
    }

    return count;
}

The total execution time is 29.3s. __builtin_assume_aligned improves performance by about 0.6s (29.9s->29.3s) on the target CPU. Any small improvements count, even if it is just 1%, I'm trying to get the most out of this code as possible.
I've thought about using more vectorization and possible register reuse. I'm guessing the conditionals on im1, ip1, jm1, jp1 might have something to do with the code not being properly vectorized. Note, there is already some vectorization going on, but, extremely minor:
  3,93 │278:   movdqu 0x0(%r13,%rdx,1),%xmm0
  0,50 │       movups %xmm0,(%rax,%rdx,1)
  1,04 │       add    $0x10,%rdx
  1,52 │       cmp    0x20(%rsp),%rdx
       │     ↑ jne    278

(perf report output, I dont really even know if this part of the code actually belongs to the function mentioned, I'm very new to this. It seems likely because of the forced __builtin_assume_aligned)
I thought of separating the edge conditions i=0, j=0, i=Y-1, j=X-1 into their own loop, in order to avoid checking this comparisons over and over again on the loop. But before doing so, I would like to know if this strategy is actually going to cause any improvements, since it is going to take a while doing it manually.

(edit: its actually not 6 code blocks, but 3*3=9)
I'd love to know your opinion about doing this optimization, so I know if it is worth taking my time. Feel free to suggest any other optimizations for this code :)!
The code will always be ran on the same CPU, an Intel Xeon E5645.
Compiler flags are: -Ofast -march=native -ffast-math, but more can be added if needed.

You don't say what are the typical values of X and Y. They must be quite large for the execution time to be ~30s. When working on large 2D arrays, it's often advantageous to process blocks at a time, due to the cache benefits. I don't know without studying in more detail if that's feasible here though.

Initialize jm1 = X - 1 before the loop and increment it at the end of the loop jm1 = (jm1 + 1) % X to avoid the conditional. Similar for jp1.

I wouldn't worry about the outer loop since optimizing the inner loop will have much greater impact.

You can increase the size of your tablero by one on each side (copying the wrap-around values), then you don't need any special case handling. You can also make sure that the number of columns matches your SIMD type. N.B.: Your code looks a lot like a Game of Life simulator, you can find a lot of existing code for that, including SIMD-optimized code.

Just a guess, but do you try to implement Conway’s Game of Life? Whats the exact purpose here? Do you want to calculate everything on a single instance, or on muliple instances of tablero? Is multithreading an option? Just spread the outer loop accross multiple threads.

yes, im trying to implement conway's game of life. i'm taking a look at the suggestions you guys made, thank you :)

@arch multithreading is not an option. also, it must be a single instance.

https://lemire.me/blog/2018/07/18/accelerating-conways-game-of-life-with-simd-instructions/ has a discussion of his SIMD implementation (https://github.com/lemire/SIMDgameoflife), and links to some better-optimized ones.  See also SSE operations to implement a loop over a 2D array where each output depends on the 3x3 square that contains it (Game of Life)
